# How to patch an entire class in python and still use its methods

Tags: python-3.x, mocking

I'm trying to patch an *entire* class in python, including the **init** that I don't want to run.
But I still need to define some return values for my methods. Is there a way to do that?

**Module.py**

```
class MyClass():
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Some API call I don't want to make when moking
        print("This shouldn't print in tests")
        
    def my_method(self, a, b):
        return a + b
    
a = MyClass()
a.my_method(1,2)
```

**test_class.py**

```
import unittest as test
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from module import MyClass

class TestClass(test.TestCase):

    # @patch("module.MyClass") # not working at all
    @patch("module.MyClass.__new__") # still calling the init
    def test_my_class(self, mock_class: MagicMock):

        mock_class.return_value.my_method.return_value = 99
        
        my_class = MyClass()
        self.assertEqual(my_class.my_method(1,1), 99)
        
test.main()
```

My naive solution was to patch MyClass.**new** but it still calls **init**. Is there an other way to achieve this?
(FYI, I'm quite new to mocking and patching so don't hesitate to tell me what I'm missing here)

Thanks a lot!